# How to get file name in SAX Parser?

Tags: java, xml, sax

Is There a way to get file name in SAX parser handler class?.
I have a requirement to write file name along with the tag content in a text file.

Please help.

EDIT: I need this

saxParser.parse("Input.xml",saxHandler);
in saxHandler when I got 'id' tag, read the value and store the value along with the filename. It can be map or object.

Comment: What file? Who said there's a file?

Comment: I read somewhere it will not read file. I could be parsing data from a string variable, but I do not have clear idea about it.  Is there no way to get file name?

Comment: If you're loading the file, you have the file name. If all you have is a parser, there not much you can do. The source can be anything.

Answer (score 2):

The SAX parser will typically call `ContentHandler.setDocumentLocator()` before calling any other event handling methods. The supplied Locator can be used to get a SystemId, and if you are parsing from a file, then the SystemId will generally give you the source file name in URI form.

Some caveats:

- The SAX parser is encouraged to call this method but it isn't obliged to do so.
- In some cases, e.g. if parsing from a FileInputStream, the source file name (and therefore SystemId) might not be known to the parser (indeed, the source XML doesn't necessarily come from a file).
- If the source document comprises multiple external entities, then the SystemId can change during the course of parsing.

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for the answer.  I suspect Michael Kay knows a lot more about this than I do, but I couldn't figure out a method from his post, so I'll post what works for me (Python 3).  In my element handler's startDocument method, I have the following:
   self.sInFName = Path(self._locator.getSystemID()).name
(This uses the Path method of PathLib, i.e. do 'from pathlib import Path' near the top of your code.)  Then I can refer to the filename of the file I'm parsing from anywhere inside the handler.  (If you want the full path to the file, omit the .name)

As others have pointed out, this only works if you're actually parsing a file.  If you're reading from stdin or something, getSystemID() will return something other than a file path (I don't know what).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Java: (Thanks Michael Kay for direction)

In fileHandler:

```
@Override
public void setDocumentLocator( Locator locator) {
    String systemId = locator.getSystemId();
    Path p = Paths.get(URI.create(systemId));
    String fileName = p.getFileName().toString();
    System.out.println(fileName);
}
```